# unit testing in javascript, first approach

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to unit testing procedures and I'm trying to figure out how to do it properly.

In my project, the javascript i wrote basically interacts with dom object via events, so i need to write a test that basically manipulate the DOM.

now, i have this project structure:

```
init
|--node_modules
|--spec
|--src
    |--assets
    |--dist
    |--js
    |--scss
    |--index.html
|--gulpfile.js
|--package.lock.json
|--package.json
```

i set up the jasmine spec folder in the root, but maybe, because i need to working whit the dom, have I to set up the spec folder inside the scr path? and then insert the test.spec.js at the end of my index.html?

for now i create this test file, for testing the Contacts.js:

```
const contactsHandler              = require('../src/js/Contacts.js');

const contacts = new contactsHandler.Contacts();


describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(typeof(contactsHandler)).toBe('object');
  });
});
```

Now if i remove the second line: `const contacts = new contactsHandler.Contacts();` test is passed, instead i will get an error.
this is my Contacts class:

```
class Contacts{
  constructor(){
    this.contactsButton = document.getElementById('contacts-button');
    this.contactsContainer = document.getElementById('contacts-container');
    this.phoneTrigger = document.getElementById('phone-trigger');
    this.mailTrigger = document.getElementById('mail-trigger');
    this.phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    this.mail = document.getElementById('mail');
    this.close = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.close-contact'));
    this.mailText = '.contacts--mail--text';
    this.phoneText = '.contacts--phone--text';
    this.init()
  }
  init(){
    this._initContacts();
    this._initPhone();
    this._initMail();
    this._close();
    this._textAnimation();

  }

  _initContacts(){
    let self = this;
    this.contactsButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
      TweenLite.from(self.contactsContainer,2,
        {
          autoAlpha:0,
        })
    })
  }

  _initPhone(){
    let self = this;
    this.phoneTrigger.addEventListener('click',function(){
      TweenLite.to(self.phone,1,{autoAlpha:1,top:'0',left:'0',zIndex:20})
      $(self.phoneText).textillate('start')
    })
  }
  _close(){
    this.close.forEach(function(el){
      el.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(this.parentElement.classList.contains('contacts--mail')){
          TweenLite.to(this.parentElement,1,{autoAlpha:0,top:'-50%'})
        }else{
          TweenLite.to(this.parentElement,1,{autoAlpha:0,top:'50%'})
        }
      })
    })
  }

  _initMail(){
    let self = this;
    this.mailTrigger.addEventListener('click',function(){
      TweenLite.to(self.mail,.7,{autoAlpha:1,top:'0',left:'0',zIndex:20})
      $(self.mailText).textillate('start')
    })
  }

  _textAnimation(){
    $(this.phoneText).textillate({
        in: { effect: 'bounceIn' },
        autoStart:false
    })
    $(this.mailText).textillate({
        in: { effect: 'bounceIn' },
        autoStart:false
    })
  }
}




module.exports = {
  Contacts
}
```

I think that i get an error because when i call the constructor it tries to reach some DOM elements, that of course couldn't find. So: have I to put the test.spec.js file into the src folder and then calling it in the html file? is it a good procedure?
thanks

Comment: "How do I unit test something which uses the DOM" is far too broad. You need to do some investigation and come back with specific problems

Comment: I update the questions